# How can I configure Heap Size and Garbage Collection in Cloudhub?

Tags: garbage-collection, mule, heap-memory, anypoint-studio, cloudhub

I am using Anypoint Cloudhub and Mule 3.8.1 and am having performance issues with my application.

Looking at performance articles on the web it looks like I should look at Heap Size and Garbage Collection to optimise performance so would like to know how I can configure these in Cloudhub?

I can see how you do it in an on-premise installation of Mule but not Cloudhub.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to increase the Heap Size in Cloud-Hub directly through configurations. In cloudhub you can assign more resources to your application by increasing the worker size, where the Worker size is having the following Heap Memory -

Worker Size Heap Memory-

- 0.1 vCores -500 MB
- 0.2 vCores -1 GB
- 1 vCores -1.5 GB
- 2 vCores -3.5 GB
- 4 vCores - 7.5 GB
- 8 vCores -16 GB
- 16 vCores -32 GB

Please note, Only running applications count for workers usage. Stopped applications do not consume vCore availability.

Workers that have less than 1 vCore capacity (0.1 vCores and 0.2 vCores)  offer limited CPU and IO for smaller work loads. Each worker has 8 GB of storage, which is used for both system and application storage.

Applications with greater storage needs (verbose logging etc.) should use one of the larger worker sizes - 2 vCores or 4 vCores, which have additional storage as follows:

1. vCores workers have an additional 4 GB of SSD storage mounted on /tmp
2. vCores workers have an additional 32 GB of SSD storage mounted on /tmp
3. vCores workers have an additional 80 GB of storage, mounted as two volumes on /tmp (40 GB), and /opt/storage (40 GB)

Let me know if you need more details on this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can get more resources by adding worker size, https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/deploying-to-cloudhub#configuring-a-deployed-application, which in turn can be used to configure the heap size.